# I can't seem to use Remote Desktop Connection on my laptop if I plug in a monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

For whatever reason, if I plug in a monitor (benq gw2765ht) to my laptop via hdmi (XPS 9560 running Windows 10 Home), I cannot use Remote Desktop Connection.

After logging in, the screen immediately turns black and closes right away. Yet if I plug out the monitor, it seems to work fine.

Anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but I'm -guessing- that you mean that you are trying to RDP to your laptop while the laptop has an external monitor connected.  Is that correct?  If so, try changing the display resolution for the RDP connection before you connect.

Comment: Thanks, changing resolution solved the issue.